# What is an simple example of copy_from_user

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696863/any-example-of-copy-from-user-kernel-and-userspace) about `copy_from_user`, but it is a little bit too advanced for me, I want to see simple example of using the `copy_from_user` method within kernel module, what is the simplest example of using that method?

```c
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init initialization_function(void)
{
    // unsigned long result = copy_from_user(, , ,);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_funcion(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Module: Bye, World.\n");
}

module_init(initialization_function);
module_exit(cleanup_funcion);
```

Comment: Instead of doing "hit and run", say what's *wrong* with my question.

Comment: Normally it makes more sense to `copy_from_user` in the context of a system call, when the user has passed you a pointer to some data to be copied and processed.  In a system call initialization function, you have no such context.

Comment: Please, note, that Stack Overflow is not a place where we write *tutorials* or provide references to those. We are Question/Answer site, and you question doesn't look like the one we could **answer**. You say that you cannot understand the existing example, but what **exactly** is not clear in it? Function `copy_from_user` could be used in the `.write` method of a file or a character device. Have you read some book or tutorial about file operations implementation in the Linux kernel? You may read e.g. the book "Linux Driver Development".

Comment: Write to /dev/urandom entropy pool in linux kernel:   https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1887

Answer (score 1):

A classic example for using copy_from_user is when you implement the `write` function of a character device. Assume you have a module that registers a [character device](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html) which receives paths of file from the user. Its code will look something like:

```c
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *fs, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    char* file_path = (char*)kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (NULL == file_path) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    copy_from_user(file_path, buffer, len);
    file_path[len - 1] = 0x00;
    
    return len;
}
```

In general, `copy_from_user` is identical to `memcpy`, but only it expects a user-space buffer as its destination.

Comment: ```copy_from_user``` copies data from user space to kernel space. Hence, it might be a typo in your last sentence, where it should be "it expects a user-space buffer as its source".