# Where do the source and destination addresses come from for copy_to/from_user()?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My goal is to instantiate a value in user space, install and run a kernel module (Ubuntu 20.04.1 if it matters) in which that value is changed/overwritten, and then print out the value in user space.  I understand that copy_to/from_user() and/or get/put_user() are used to do things like this, but what I don't understand is this: How does the kernel module get the address to which it copies data? Does the user space program pass a pointer to it by calling the kernel module method that changes the value? Does the user program pass its PID to kernel module when installing/running it via bash and some how using the PID the kernel accesses the user program's memory space? Should I be tackling this a different way, such as having the kernel module instantiate the value and the user program access it and print it out?

If it matters, yes, this question is motivated by a homework assignment, however it is not the homework assignment, it is what I'm using to test my design of the homework assignment.

Sample user program:

```c
// blah blah blah C stuff

int main(void)
{
    double val = 2.78;
    // call a bash script to insmod the kernel module
    while (val == 2.78);    // wait for the kernel module to change the value (yes, busy waiting sucks)
    printf("val = %f\n", val);    // print the changed value
    return 0;
}
```

Sample kernel module:

```c
// more C stuff

static int mod_init(void)
{
    double kval = 3.14;
    copy_to_user(&val, &kval, sizeof(double));   // how do I do this?
    return 0;
}
```

I've read through other questions/answers on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408888/passing-linked-list-via-copy-from-user) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696863/any-example-of-copy-from-user-kernel-and-userspace), and I've read the relevant chapters of my text book (LDD3, ch 3, 6), and the sample code that it provides, but I'm still confused.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  Thanks for your help SO.  Haven't finished my homework assignment yet, but I think I'm now on the right track.  For those with this question in the future: `copy_to/from_user` is (for lack of a better term) wrapped by an `ioctl`, which is essentially a cut rate system call.  [This](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/ioctl-tutorial-in-linux/) helped me understand `ioctls` from the user perspective (warning: it's a really really gross website).  LDD3 ch 3 helped flesh out the kernel side.

Comment: Normally you read data from the kernel by calling a function, like `read` or `ioctl`. The pointer is one of the arguments to the function. The kernel doesn't just change data by itself.

Comment: The addresses are passed as parameters in a relevant system call.

Comment: And how do you get a file descriptor for `read` or `ioctl`? You open a file in `/dev` which the driver creates. Unfortunately I don't know enough about it to write an answer. But this is how most drivers work. They create a `/dev` file for each device they know about (like a hard disk) - for drivers that don't actually have a device (like your test driver) they just create one for the whole driver. Then the program opens it and does reads and writes and ioctls